# jQuery not working when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have built a simple page on my localhost and then I have uploaded it on the net. When the page is viewed from local machine, all jQuery interactions works well without any problem. But when I view the hosted page, nothing happens. It seems a plugin + jQuery are not loaded properly, though I see them loaded (using firefox view source code, I check the scripts address and see their source without 404 error).

I appreciate any help. Here is the address:

http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer/

The jQuery interaction is that when the user clicks on the search bar, a box slides down which contains many search-categories.
And also the thumbnails at the bottom of the red line moves when mouse hovers it. Now, you probably wouldn't see any of these stories.

The page is written using codeigniter.

EDIT EDIT

the scripts and CSS are loaded automatically using a library written for codeigniter. But the generated HTML markup for browser is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer/js/blue/2-prettyCheckable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer/js/blue/1-jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer/js/blue/mtSlideElement.js"></script>
```

Comment: please provide the code that brings in jQuery (the script tag in your `head`).

Comment: There are errors in the console when the page loads. Take a look there.

Comment: I have taken. I do not know why errors are reported because all the required scripts are loaded...

Comment: change `$(document).ready(function(){..` to `$(window).ready(function(){`

Comment: the order of the scripts also could not be a problem since I loaded even a hosted jQuery on top of everything to ensure its load.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prettyCheckable' `

Comment: I tested it, but still fails to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prettyCheckable is a jQuery plugin, you need to include it after you call jquery, change the order you are including the scripts so it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer/js/blue/1-jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer/js/blue/2-prettyCheckable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

2-prettyCheckable.js has a semicolon as its first character and there is no method called prettyCheckable in it. Did a few lines get cut out of this script by accident?

Comment: The unnecessary `;` won't cause a problem at all.  Better too many than not enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have loaded two `jQuery`, at first `jQuery v1.10.2` and then `prettyCheckable.js` and then again `jQuery v1.10.1`, this is the problem because, once `prettyCheckable` extended the core `jQuery` and then you loaded again another `jQuery` and it's completely new. This the order

```
http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer/js/blue/1-jquery.js // loaded
http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer/js/blue/2-prettyCheckable.js // jQuery.fn extended
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js // old jQuery replaced
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pages has two 'html', 'head' tags, you might want to remove them. And put all those javascript into a single.js file and call include it just before  tag.

There is are definition for `prettyCheckable();`